# Android Firebase Query to find by key without value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a query that will get me all elements that has "2005" under categories list.

I've tried this deep nesting but it got me all results (both 2005 and 2006)

```
Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("categories/2005");
```

The reason I want to do it with Query and not eventlistener is because the list is big and I want to do as much as filtering as i can on the cloud.

Sorry but I haven't found a solution for this on other posts.
I could only find how to query by value.

[image: DB structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit non-intuitive, but this works:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("categories/2005")
                 .startAt("-");
```

The trick is to pick a start value that is lower in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) than `0`. I picked `-` because it reads nicely, but if you have a broader range of values you'll want to use a space as starting point, which is the lowest printable character.

Working jsbin: https://jsbin.com/viyibij/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you Frank, that actually works. Just to verify. What starts at "-" ? The value at 0, right ?